# How can I drag and drop a list item to a image view (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf

What I want is to drag and drop a list item from a listbox to an imageView in WPF.

So I have a listbox with some list items like: circle1, circle2 and an imageView with a picture.
Now I want to drag and drop one list item on this picture. And this list item is shown as a circle on this picture.

Is this possible?

My Main WPF with listbox and image:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.ControlCentre.UI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CLock.ControlCentre.UI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MyProject - ControlCentre" Height="391" Width="767" Icon="/Images/MyIcon.ico">

<Grid Background="#FF2B2B2B" Height="376">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu x:Name="menuControlCentre" Margin="0,0,0,311" Background="#FF2B2B2B">
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuItemControlCentre" Header="_File" Foreground="White">
            <MenuItem x:Name="mItemLogInCC" Header="_LogIn" Foreground="Black"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="mItemLoadImageCC" Header="_Load Image" Foreground="Black" Click="mItemLoadImageCC_Click"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="meItemExitCC" Header="_Exit" Foreground="Black" Click="menueItemExitControlCentre_Click"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <ListBox x:Name="lbxCircles" Margin="10,58,562,23" Background="White" SelectionChanged="lbxDoors_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Label Content="Türen:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="26" Width="44"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgPlanOfRoom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="247,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="487"/>
    <Label Content="Plan of Room:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried doing it with AllowDrop and stuff but it didn't work. I don't know how to implement the function that the list item converts into a circle and gets dropped on an imageView.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Hello, Have you googled your question? There seem to be some posts online such as: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/

Comment: I did but I didn't find anything helpful for my case.

Comment: I just quickly skimmed over the article but you should find everything in there about the DragAndDrop functionalities. The drawing of shapes can surely be found somewhere else.